# Let's say I have a column and I want to see if the same value shows up within 5 indexes away

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example:

Column1 
0 
0 
1 
0 
0 
1 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
1

I want to create another column that would mark '1' if column 1 has more than a single 1 within 5 indexes from each other where:

|Col1  |Col2 |
|:----:|:---:|
|  0   |  0  |
|0     |  0  | 
|1     |     0 |
|0     |     0 |
|0     |     0 |
|1      |      1 | <--because index 2 in column 1 has a 1 and index 5 has a 1, it gets a 1 
|0     |     0 | 
|0     |     0 |
|0     |     0 |
|0     |     0 |
|0     |     0 |
|1     |   0  |<- there is no 1 in column2 because the next closest 1 is more than 5 indexes away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html#pandas.Series.rolling) window of length 5 and see if the `sum` over this window is greater than 1, i.e. if there are other values of 1 in the window than the current one. `True`/`False` converts to `1`/`0`, so you can simply cast the boolean result to `int` to get the desired result.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]})

df['Col2'] = (df.Col1.eq(1) & df.Col1.rolling(5, min_periods=0).sum().gt(1)).astype(int)
```

```
    Col1  Col2
0      0     0
1      0     0
2      1     0
3      0     0
4      0     0
5      1     1
6      0     0
7      0     0
8      0     0
9      0     0
10     0     0
11     1     0
```

---

If you want to look for 1s in both directions, you can use a centered window of length 11 instead:

```
(df.Col1.eq(1) & df.Col1.rolling(11, center=True, min_periods=0).sum().gt(1)).astype(int)
```